# How to change the appearance of the file picker title on Android?

Tags: android

I want to show a file picker to open an image using this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose from"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

How can I change the font and gravity of the file picker title ("choose from")?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I found by digging in the Android source code:

[`createChooser`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#907) creates an intent with an [`ACTION_CHOOSER`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#859) action.
When you launch your intent, a [`ChooserActivity`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ChooserActivity.java) is created (not sure how exactly) which extends [`ResolverActivity`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java). The layout applied to `ResolverActivity` is [`resolver_list`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list.xml) or [`resolver_list_with_default`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list_with_default.xml). In there you can find the [`title`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list.xml#34) in question.

So, no, it doesn't seem to be possible to change the appearance of the file picker title. But you could create your custom file chooser based on the original source code.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can change the color/font/gravity of this chooser dialog as this is invoked/managed by system and not by your app, except the attributes like what title to show (talking specifically about chooser dialog).