# Title for File Chooser

Tags: java, android

I have a task where the user has to pick *two* files. I do not like the option to display a dialog before hands, saying *Please pick the first file now, and then the second!"*, so I would like to display a title over the file chooser.

This is my (example) code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_FIRST = 1, FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_SECOND = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chooseFirstFile();
    }

    private void chooseFirstFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        Intent finalIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select first file");
        startActivityForResult(finalIntent, FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_FIRST);
    }

    private void chooseSecondFile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        Intent finalIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select second file");
        startActivityForResult(finalIntent, FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_SECOND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_FIRST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v("TEST", "First file is " + data.toString());
            chooseSecondFile();
        } else if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSE_RESULT_SECOND && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.v("TEST", "Second file is " + data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I add a title to the file chooser ("Select first file" and "Select the second file"), but it doesn't get shown:

[image: ScreenShot of File Chooser]

How can I actually show the file chooser's title?

I've seen the question this one can be seen as a duplicate of, but I did not understand it to answer it, because it asks about the gravity and style of the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the appearance of the file picker title on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248679/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-the-file-picker-title-on-android)

Comment: I've already seen that question, but I wouldn't have guessed that it is about showing the title at all as well.

Comment: Well, the title of that question wasn't the greatest and you are right to be confused. This question is better asked, so maybe this will be better for future readers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that. File Picker is based on the `ResolverActivity`. As evident from this post: [How to change the appearance of the file picker title on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248679/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-the-file-picker-title-on-android), there is this info:

> [`createChooser`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#907) creates an intent with an [`ACTION_CHOOSER`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#859) action.
>   When you launch your intent, a [`ChooserActivity`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ChooserActivity.java) is created (not sure how exactly) which extends [`ResolverActivity`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/app/ResolverActivity.java). The layout applied to `ResolverActivity` is [`resolver_list`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list.xml) or [`resolver_list_with_default`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list_with_default.xml). In there you can find the [`title`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/resolver_list.xml#34) in question.

There is no way to do that as you can't change the title, which is you could say `"read-only"`. But as the answer from the other question also tells, you can create your custom file chooser based on the original source code. Or using a [Document Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) create a custom navigator.